# Storing MongoDB document inside a Node.js array and return it

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, async-await

I try to get specific documents from MongoDB with Node.js and insert them into array.

```
  const getStockComments = async (req) => {
  const stockname = req.params.stockName;
  var comments = [];
  var data = [];

  const stock = await stockModel.findOne({ name: stockname });
  comments = stock.comments;
  comments.forEach(async (commentId) => {
    const comm = await commentModel.findOne({ _id: commentId });
    data.push(comm);
    console.log(data); // This returns the data in loops, because its inside a loop.
  });
  console.log(data); // This not returns the data and i don't know why.
  return data;
};
```

The first console.log(data) returns the same data a lot of times because its inside a loop.
But the second console.log(data) dosen't returns the data at all.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using loop , you can use $in operator to simplify things .

```
const getStockComments = async (req) => {
  const stockname = req.params.stockName;
  var comments = [];
  var data = [];

  const stock = await stockModel.findOne({ name: stockname });
  comments = stock.comments;
  commentModel.find({ _id: { $in: comments } }, (err, comments) => {
    data = comments;
  });
  console.log(data);
  return data;
};
```